# Is this the correct use of "will it"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, future-tense

Once the spirit is broken, only when the human has lost all hope WILL IT be transferred to the soul extraction chamber.

It should be "it will be" for conditionals here, right??

Comment: Apart from what FF said, the sentence sounds  little off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "will it" part makes sense. Because of the beginning of the phrase, "only when," you are able to use "will it" instead of "it will"

However, the sentence does not altogether make sense to me. "Once the spirit is broken" seems out of place and may need to be reworded.